# Perl script to split a file and process then concatenate based on size and a string

Tags: regex, perl, split, concatenation, file-handling

Could somebody help me to get some logic to following in perl I am using windows 7.

C:\script>perl split_concatenate.pl large_file a or b
(Input would be large file and value a or b to process it later).

1. Check the file if it is greater than 40KB (some size), and choice is "a" , if not run a command

command -i large_file.txt -o large_file_new  -a

else if the choice is b

command -i large_file.txt -o large_file_new  -b

else

if it is greater say 40KB+, split the file for each 40KB arround (will be part1,) and append a first "particular string" which will be in the file_part2 to the part1 save it for processing, if there are multiple "particular string" then create subsequent files which should end with next "particular string" in the following part. ("Particular String" starts with some String  but ends in different value). So script should search if there are more "Particular string", in the part2 or so and append first available one, if there is only one available no need to anything just split. As file always should end with a particular string.

Then process same command

command -i filepart1.txt -o filepart1.dat -a 
command -i filepart2.txt  - o filepart2.dat (if needed) -a

or

command -i filepart1.txt -o filepart1.dat -b
command -i filepart2.txt  - o filepart2.dat (if needed) -b

After this needs to be concatenated.

Concatenate filepart1.dat + filepart2.dat + filepartN =large_file.dat

I started to find the size first using below code,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use File::stat;

    my $filesize = stat("Full_File.txt")->size;

    print "Size: $filesize\n";

    exit 0;
```

It will be great if some one help so I can learn. If this is not possible, then @ each 500th line the file reaches to 40KB, so I think this would be easier, every 500th line append the Next available "Particular String", and split and process above command, if file is less than 1000 lines then only 2 split and no need to append in the part2 as already it has one in its eof. May be easier?

Better explanation:

large_file.txt

```
xxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
var:value_var_v(1234)
xxxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
var:value_var_v(4567)
xxxxxxx
xxxxxx
var:value_var_v(abcd)
xxxxxxx  // first split happens here as here assume it is 40kb
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
var:value_var_v(efgh)
```

If this is too big then
split at line 5, say `large_files_part1`. Its end should contain `var:value_var_v(1234)`. After the 5th line it should split again at line 9 and will become `large_files_part2` and have `var:value_var_v(4567)` at the end.
part3 wil go till line 12 and include `var:value_var_v(abcd)` at the end, and so on. If there is only one `var:value_var_v?` after the first split then
only two parts is fine as long as the lines in both parts is arround 500. If there are say 1300 line in the main file then three splits are needed. The end of each file should have the  next available "string", so the 1001st line will be the first `var:value_var_v(1234)` available after line 1000. String always starts with var:value_var_v, end with any thing. Hope this is clear.

Output Expected:
    First case: 
So, out put will be, _part1.txt will be arround 40,000 if it had only one occurrence of string

```
xxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
var:value_var_v(1234)
xxxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
var:value_var_v(4567)
xxxxxxx
xxxxxx
var:value_var_v(abcd)
xxxxxxx  // split happened here
var:value_var_v(efgh)

_part2.txt
xxxxxxx
xxxxx
var:value_var_v(efgh)
```

After  I do some process on these files (part1 and par2) I again concatenate

_part1+_part2=large+file

Final large_file after concatenation:

```
    xxx
    xxxx
    xxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(1234)
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(4567)
    xxxxxxx
    xxxxxx
    var:value_var_v(abcd)
    xxxxxxx  // split happened here
    var:value_var_v(efgh)
    ****
  xxxxxxx
  xxxxx
  var:value_var_v(efgh)
```

2nd splitting and concatenate case:

If that file is too big say 80KB and has many strings "var:value_var() after a first split @40KB,do subsequent splits where it sees
a next string which will be again "var:value_var_v()" and do a split, based on the string else based on the size. Everytime the file pat
shoudl contain next available var:value_var_v().

Orginal file:

```
    xxx
    xxxx
    xxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(1234)
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(4567)  
    xxxxxxx 
- - // assume now split happens here as here assume it is 40kb there are two more strings starting with var:value_var_v, split after var:value_var_v(abcd) and print this string in previous parts eof. Then final part will be ending with var:value_var_v(efgh). keep as it is.
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(abcd)
    xxxxxxx  
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxxx
    var:value_var_v(efgh)



part1.txt 
   xxx
    xxxx
    xxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(1234)
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(4567)  
    xxxxxxx - - // split happens here as here assume it is 40kb
    var:value_var_v(abcd) - //prints next available string which is var:value_var_v(abcd)
    _part2.txt
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(abcd)  

// Here part1 and part2 ends with same string.

    _part3.txt
    xxxxxxx  
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxxx
    var:value_var_v(efgh) - This is last part and size should be below 40KB
```

process all of these part1,part2,part3 then concatenate to a big file.

Final file after concatenating

Full fille would look like.

```
xxx
    xxxx
    xxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(1234)
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(4567)  
    xxxxxxx // split happened here in the first split assumed 40KB 
    var:value_var_v(abcd) 
      ******
    xxxxxx
   xxxxxx
    xxxxx
    var:value_var_v(abcd)  
     ******
   xxxxxxx  
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxxx
    var:value_var_v(efgh)
   ******
```

PS: Once I get processed end of in each part I get **** a unique value and retain it as it during concatenation.

Comment: What is the "particular string"? You said it will be in file_part2, but how does the script find it?

Comment: This is a string that's hard-coded into the script, a pattern that it looks for in the file, or a parameter to the script? It's already in the file, or it's something that the script adds to the file?

Comment: Its hard coded in the file, and needs to go to the end of the file if it is split. Basically the script should take the first available pattern if any after the split. In case if there are many similar strings after 500th line and before 1000th line it should split and append first available "var:value_var_v1" @ the end of split file.

Comment: I still don't understand. You say "append a first particular string", which means the script adds it. But you also say "script should search if there are more particular string", which means that it's already in the file. I think it would help if you showed some sample data. Show what the original file would look like, and what you want the result to be like.

Comment: Sorry, Let me put this way. @ the end of each file that "string" should be there.

Comment: Sorry, for poor explanation, I edited the example, hope this is clear :).

Comment: It sounds like you want to split files bigger than 40KB. The splits must be immediately after the last line that starts with `var:value_var_v` before the 40KB boundary. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm still missing something, or you messed up your example. Where did `var:value_var_v(efgh)` come from, since it wasn't in large_file.txt? And what happened to `var:value_var_v(lmop)`. What is this file all about, and what do these strings mean, why are you splitting it up this way? Maybe if I understood the application I could figure it out, because you are totally incapable of describing what you need. I've already spent more time on this horrible question than any other I've ever tried to answer, and gotten nowhere.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that question as there was another thread going on, displayed it was an accident, it had to be lmnop, I intended to write lmnop. Basically if I do not split process these files and concatenate  and it can not feed into particular DB program, unless this is splitted because of size issue. After split I have to process those files.

Comment: @Bordin, You are correct. Explained better with example :).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty close to what you want.

```
my $part_string = 'var:value_var_v';
my $file_count = 1;
my $total_length = 0;
my $max_length = 40000;

open (my $input, '<', $input_filename);
open (my $output, '>', "${output_filename}_part_${file_count}");
while (my $line = <$input>) {
  print $output $line;
  $total_length += length($line);
  if ($total_length > $max_length) {
    print $output "$part_string$file_count\n";
    close $output;
    $file_count++;
    open ($output, '>', "${output_filename}_part_${file_count}");
    $total_length = 0;
  }
}
if ($total_length > 0) {
  print $output "$part_string$file_count\n";
}
close $output;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I run this? I tried nothing happened.

Comment: I changed the value $input_filename, to my test.txt it created _part_1 but nothing in it.

Comment: When I enabled warnings, Global symbol "$full" requires explicit package name at split.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$output_filename" requires explicit package name at split.pl line
 10.
Global symbol "$output_filename" requires explicit package name at split.pl line
 18.
Bareword "test" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at split.pl line 9.
Execution of split.pl aborted due to compilation errors. I am using windows.

Comment: This is just an excerpt from the program, you need to write the rest. I expect you to initialize the ifilename variables from the arguments or however you want. I don't have a variable `$full`, so I don't know what you did to cause that -- but the error usually means that you forgot to use `my` when initializing it. I assume you know how to program, and are just having trouble with this algorithm.

Comment: I can hardly understand what you're trying to do, I'm not going to write the whole thing for you. If you don't know perl that well, use another language that you know better. My script should help you with the general algorithm, which is the same in any language.

Comment: Okay, Could you explain what is my $max_length = 40000;? Is this line number or the size? Trying to understand the  logic behind.

Comment: It's the size. Do you see where I add the length of each line to `$total_length`, and then compare this to `$max_length`? You said the file has to be split every 40000 characters.

Comment: Oh okay, 40000 character is same as 40kB? I did not think in this way, It is interesting. If that is the case it may work. But right now it did not do anything, I put the file name to test it it created the part1 but did not print the characters. Trying out.

Comment: 46,994 characters is 47.8 KB so almost equal. Thats is really interesting. Good thinking.!

Comment: Ah my bad, this splits on each file and increments the string value, actually 1,2,3,4 is different not incremental. Any idea.? Now I am able to run it (getting into it) but logic needs to be revised.

Comment: WHat are you trying to say? That seems to be exactly what you wrote in the question, it doesn't add any new information.

Comment: I updated the question, how output would look like.

Comment: You updated the question 16 hours ago, I posted a question 14 hours ago (up in the main comment area, since it's not about my answer). Then 7 hours later you wrote that you updated the question, but you didn't answer my question about where (efgh) came from when it wasn't in the input file. I give up.

Comment: There were  two threads going on so I missed the question, I corrected it now above. Will discuss only one place.

Comment: Okay, I reformatted to very simple. Commented where would the split happens.

Comment: Only thing after first split if there multiple similar strings first available string should go end of the previous part, any time the parts should have next available string meanwhile the file should not exceed more than say 40KB. This must be clear... :).